# DB modeling: does this non-identifiable relationship maintain identifiability?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have some tables and I have used MySQL Workbench to create `role_has_action` table.
The fields created were: (`role_id`,`action_id`,`action_controller_id`):
(I renamed `action_controller_id` to `controller_id` for brevity):
[image: identifying relationship]

I understand that it is an identifying relationship, between `role_has_action` and `action` table.  `action` table has a composite key from itself, and the controller table.  Hence, `role_has_action` table now has a triple-composite primary key to maintain identifiable relationship.

I claim, however, that if `role_has_action` has only (`role_id`,`action_id`) fields, then identifiability will be preserved in practice, although maybe not in the strict theoretic sense.  I say that because, controllers are unique; actions are unique with respect to controllers; and `role_has_action` can tie a role from `role` table to an action uniquely by using action.id column, and hence `controller_id` key is superfluous in `role_has_action` table.

Did I miss something?  Removing that column (`controller_id`) has MySQL Workbench mark this relationship as non-identifying, so I am somewhat concerned.  Can I have a counter-example of how this becomes a non-identifying relationship, or am I alright in practice removing that column and not worrying much about losing identifiability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formally speaking, in an identifying relationship, the child entity's primary key *must* include its parents' primary keys. MySQLWorkbench seems to follow this strict definition.

Since `action` is defined as entertaining an identifying relationship with `controller` (which is arguably correct), the strict rule requires that `controller_id` be part of `action`'s primary key, and cascaded down to `role_has_action`

But assuming that `action.id` is unique, this column becomes *practically* superfluous.

However, uniqueness of `action.id` is not *formally* required (in fact, this is a [surrogate key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key), and its very existence is optional). You could very well drop this column and let  `(name, conroller_id)` be the primary key. In this case, `role_has_action.controller_id` would be *practically* required again.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, removing `controller_id` from `role_has_action` will indeed cause relational integrity concerns, since the only way to uniquely define an `action` is by both the `id` and `controller_id` fields.  By including `controller_id` into the primary key for `action`, you are effectively saying "The same action can be used with multiple controllers."  Therefore, the only way to know which actions/controllers you're talking about is to look at both of those IDs; otherwise it's ambiguous.  If this is not true "in real life", then you may need to rethink your relational model.

If every single record in the `action` table is guaranteed to have a unique `id` value, then the "quick and dirty" way of fixing this would be to remove `controller_id` from its primary key (but keep it as a foreign key with the `controller` table).  This would allow you to then remove `controller_id` from the primary key of the `role_has_action` table, since you can now uniquely identify the action by the `action_id`.  My concern with this approach is that the `action` table becomes a bit difficult to understand: the table structure implies that every single action is unique, though only by virtue of the (likely artificially-generated) `id` column, which implies that some database-external logic must be going on to ensure the business function of data in the table is consistent and correct, which just continues to open up subsequent cans of worms.

What you might try instead is to adjust your relational model to something like the following:

- `role` table: a definition of all available roles (primary key: `role_id`)
- `action` table: a definition of all available actions (primary key: `action_id`)
- `controller` table: a definition of all available controllers (primary key: `controller_id`)
- `role_has_action`: a list of actions that belong to each role (primary key: `role_id, action_id`, foreign keys with `role` and `action` tables)
- `controller_has_action`: a list of actions that belong to each controller (key: `controller_id, action_id`, foreign keys with `controller` and `action` tables)

You require one additional table in this model, but all possible roles, actions, and controllers are uniquely defined and relationships between them are unambiguous and clear.

Comment: "The same action can be used with multiple controllers.". Probably not, the identifying relationship requires `(action_id, controller_id)` to be a foreign key to `action`'s primary key.